# Create a mesh from GLTFLaoder().load() in Thre.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, 3d-model

I have a local 3D object model and I load it with:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load("path/to/model", gltf => {
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
});
```

How should I create a `mesh` out of the gltf, because when I try:

```
loader.load("path/to/model", (geometry, materials) => {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
  scene.add(mesh);
  mesh.position.z = -10;
});
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert undefined to object

Comment: glTF files may contain an entire scene graph, with many meshes and materials. There's no general way to reduce the entire scene graph down to a single mesh without throwing away most of that information. You can create a list of meshes, or pick out a specific mesh by name, but you can't represent the whole model as a single mesh, unless you've carefully designed the model to have nothing else in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that actually by modifying the first function above like this:

```
loader.load("path/to/model", gltf => {
  var object = gltf.scene.children[0];
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
});
```

is the solution.
Because now `object` variable can be totally handled like a normal mesh.
Maybe a [video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=1TeMXIWRrqE&si=EnSIkaIECMiOmarE) to help you.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to say `scene.add(object)` then? Otherwise I don't see how assigning `object` makes a difference.